# Mapbox GL: Possible to move navigation controls?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Would anyone know if it is possible to move the navigation controls from top-right to top-left? By default, it is top-right, but I would like to add a company's logo at that position and I've seen other Mapbox maps with controls on the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be possible w/o hacking the DOM:

```
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.Navigation({position: 'top-left'}));
```

See the [docs](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Navigation).

*Note*: haven't tried this; as w/ [attribution](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Attribution), might be necessary to set the default navigation control to `false` when initializing the map.

Comment: This won't work - position is not a parameter for Navigation. Instead the answer by @max-kaplan is correct.

Answer (score 14):

I could not get it to work with @james-conkling 's example above. I did this instead:

```
var nav = new mapboxgl.NavigationControl();
map.addControl(nav, 'top-left');
```

Comment: This worked for me with the newest versions of mapbox gl

Comment: Is there any way to center the control? I've tried 

.mapboxgl-ctrl-top-right{
    top: 0;
    right: 50%;
}

but it places the right end of the control on the middle of the screen, but I wnat the middle of the control to be in the middle of the screen

Comment: The one from James Conkling didn't work on my map but this one from Max Kaplin did. Thanks Max.

Answer (score 2):

For the most recent version correct answer is:

```
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl(), 'top-left');
```